# How to edit a file in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and trying to write a program for a hotel and let customers edit their booking details such as first name, last name...etc. The code I wrote can be run but the data in the file is not edited.

The else statement for the line  `("Record not found! Please enter your Username and Password again.\n");` is not printed when I entered the wrong username and password as well.

Here is what I got so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdbool.h>

struct customer_details  // Structure declaration
{
    char uname[100];
    char pass[100];
    char fname[100];
    char lname[100];
    char ic[100];
    char contact[100];
    char email[100];
    char room[100];
    char day[100];
 }s;


void main()
{
    FILE* f, *f1;
    f = fopen("update.txt", "r");
    f1 = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    char uname[100], pass[100];
    int valid = 0;

   // validate whether file can be opened.
   if (f == NULL)
   {
       printf("Error opening file!\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   printf("Please enter your Username and Password to update your booking detail.\n");
   printf("\nUsername: ");
   fgets(uname, 100, stdin);
   uname[strcspn(uname, "\n")] = 0;
   printf("Password: ");
   fgets(pass, 100, stdin);
   pass[strcspn(pass, "\n")] = 0;
   while (fscanf(f, "%s %s", s.uname, s.pass) != -1)
   {
       if (strcmp(uname, s.uname) == 0 && strcmp(pass, s.pass) == 0)
       {
           valid = 1;
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("Record found!\n");
           printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
           scanf("%s", &s.fname);
           printf("\nEnter Last Name: ");
           scanf("%s", &s.lname);
           printf("\nEnter IC Number: ");
           scanf("%s", &s.ic);
           printf("\nEnter Contact Number:");
           scanf("%s", &s.contact);
           printf("\nEnter Email: ");
           scanf("%s", &s.email);
           printf("\nEnter Room ID :");
           scanf("%s", &s.room);
           printf("\nEnter Days of staying:");
           scanf("%s", &s.day);
           fseek(f, sizeof(s), SEEK_CUR); //to go to desired position infile
           fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, f1);
        }
       else
           ("Record not found! Please enter your Username and Password again.\n");
   }
   fclose(f);
   fclose(f1);
   if (valid == 1)
   {
    
       f = fopen("update.txt", "r");
       f1 = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
       while (fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, f1))
       {
           fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, f);
       }
       fclose(f);
       fclose(f1);
       printf("Record successfully updated!\n");
   }
}
```

This is what the update.txt file contains:

abc   123   First   Last   234   33667   hi@gmail.com   101   3

Comment: Your data input into e.g. `f.name` is wrong. You are passing a pointer to a character array, when you should be passing the character array itself: `scanf("%s", s.fname);`
Don't skip lessons. All of the file handling is totally irrelevant as long as you can't get the simple stuff right. Enable errors and warnings in your compiler and you would have noticed.

Comment: but i am using 'scanf("%s", s.fname);' @Cheatah

Comment: No, you are not. What do you think `&` means?

Comment: You need & to get a pointer to an int, but an array is always converted to a pointer when passed to a function.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the *printf* call, change

```
("Record not found! Please enter your Username and Password again.\n");
```

to

```
printf("Record not found! Please enter your Username and Password again.\n");
```

If you compile your program with warnings enabled you should get a warning like

```
t.c:68:12: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
            ("Record not found! Please enter your Username and Password again.\n");
            ^
```